# Laravel - Get data from pivot table only if it appears in there

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

A `criteria` `belongsToMany` `Alerts`, and vice versa.

They are connected through a pivot table - `alert_criteria`. But, a criteria and alert doesn't have to be in the pivot table. They are added if other criteria are met.

The columns are:

`alert_id` and `criteria_id`.

Currently, this gets all `criteria` related to the user:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $alerts = Criteria::with('coordinate', 'alerts', 'alertsCount', 'bedrooms')
        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
            array('alerts' => $alerts));
    }
```

What I want to do is

> get all criteria relating to the user that appears in the pivot table of `alerts_criteria`.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you actually want something like this:

```
Auth::user() // the current user...
    ->criteria() // get any related criteria
    ->has( 'alerts' ) // which have alerts
    ->get();
```

Or if your User isn't related to Criteria:

```
Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() ) // Criteria where user_id = Auth::id()
        ->has( 'alerts' ) // which have alerts
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Joe, you was correct. Your first answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using:

```
Criteria::find(Auth::user()->id)
->alerts()
->get();
```

Comment: Two things: first, this can be simplified to `Criteria::find( Auth::id() )->alerts;`, but second, if the `Criteria::$id` is not always the same as the `User::$id`, you'll get some very strange behaviour

Comment: This is definitely not what you want, you don't share `user` primary key and `criteria` primary key, do you?

Comment: Within the `criteria` table, I have assigned a foreign key - `user_id`.